# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on references an unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Simple scenario:

- an AdmisRejet can be linked to a Admis or a PreCandidat.
- Admis and PreCandidat can have many AdmisRejet.

All was working when I only had Admis and AdmisRejet.

But then I add PreCandidat (the same way as Admis), I get an hibernate error.

Can't find out why...

Model (they all have getters and setters and ids):

```
// package nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO
@Entity
public class AdmisRejet {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADMIS_ID")
    private Admis admis;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAND_KEY")
    private PreCandidat preCandidatRejet;

// package nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO
@Entity
public class Admis {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "admis", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AdmisRejet> admisRejet;

// package nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.pgiCocktailDAO.entity
@Entity
public class PreCandidat {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "preCandidatRejet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AdmisRejet> admisRejet;
```

The dao configuration:

```
package nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO;


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "parcoursupEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "parcoursupTransactionManager")
public class ParcoursupDAOConfig {

    @Value("${datasource.parcoursup-admis.hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto}")
    private String ddlMode;

    @Value("${datasource.parcoursup-admis.jdbc.driverClassName:#{null}}")
    private String driver;


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager parcoursupTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(parcoursupEntityManagerFactory().getObject()));
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean parcoursupEntityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", ddlMode);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect");

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(parcoursupDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ParcoursupDAOConfig.class.getPackage().getName());
        factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.parcoursup-admis")
    public DataSource parcoursupDataSource() {
        if (driver != null) {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName(driver)
                    .build();
        }
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO.AdmisRejet.preCandidatRejet references an unknown entity: nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.pgiCocktailDAO.entity.PreCandidat

Comment: Have you listed all entities in the persistence.xml?

If so, then you should add PreCandidat there as well.

Comment: Can add on some more details like hibernate.cfg.xml and all the classes associated with the issue ?

Comment: Can you post the entites with their package names and your hibernate/JPA configuration in order to troubleshoot?

Comment: There is no .xml config file. Everything is with annotations. I add the packages

Comment: Are you sure your entities are in same package with `ParcoursupDAOConfig` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's because you tell the `factoryBean` that your entities are in the `factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ParcoursupDAOConfig.class.getPackage().getName());` package, which is `nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.admisDAO`. and `PreCandidat` is in the `nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao.pgiCocktailDAO.entity` package...

Try `factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("nc.unc.importparcoursup.dao")` or move your class config to a higher level.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be forget to add the annotations @Table(name = "table_name") to the entity.